# how to load localhost in swift

Tags: swift, uiwebview

guys, I have created an ios app which is based on web view. before launching I have to test it but I can't load my localhost in my testing app

I have tried this method

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>192.168.0.189</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>ExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>localhost:port</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Is any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>192.168.0.189</key>
        <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: @StephenBalaji hmm I edited my answer. Not sure you tried this already, but if you didn't try this one too. I hope it works!

Comment: still its shows white screen.. let me know if there is anyother  ways.. thanks for your reply @User18474728